# Sort Ascending - Linked List

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

I'm having a little trouble with getting my head around how this function would work and what I need to do. I have int number as my data type and  node* next in my node class. I also have node pointers head, current and temp. My question is how would I go about getting my list of integers into order? Also how does ascending and decending work in a single linked list?

My header file:

```
#ifndef SDI_LL                      
#define SDI_LL                      

namespace SDI
{                                                       

    class LinkedList                                                                    
    {
        class Node                                      
        {
        public:
            int number;                                 //data element
            Node* next;                                 //pointer to next, node inside each node
        private:

        };

    private:

        Node *head;
        Node *current;                                  //head, current and temp node pointers
        Node *temp;

    public:
        LinkedList();                                   //constructor to access nodes from above
        ~LinkedList();                                  //destructor

        void insert(int add);                           
        void remove(int remove);                        //functions that access private data nodes above
        void display();
        void reverse();
        void search(int searchNum);
        void sortAscending();
        void sortDecending();
        void saveAll();
        void restoreAll();

    };

}
#endif
```

My ascending function so far where it starts from the beginning and searches through the list:

```
void LinkedList::sortAscending()
{
    current = head;
    for (current = head; current;)
    {
        temp = current;
        current = current->next;

    }
}
```

Comment: For an internal list, such as std::list, there is a special sort for lists, std::list::sort, but the nodes are maintained within the class and the class functions copy the node data between the internal nodes and some user specified type (like a structure), that does not include links. However in this case, you're creating your own class of nodes and functions such as your own sort, so the standard functions won't help.

Comment: @Ryan - For this list sort, do you want to swap the data in the nodes or swap the nodes?

Comment: "put on hold" - the original poster is planning to update his question with the actual example code for the sort function later. One of the answers includes example code to swap data. It's unknown if the original poster plans to swap data or to swap nodes.

Comment: @MSalters: true. I've expected a specialization. Wrong comment deleted.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should use containers available in the standard libraries, which provide efficient sorting methods where applicable.

That said, if you want to do it for learning purposes - as you probably "should at least once" - then it is not too difficult to implement.

```
for (current = head; current;)
```

That's a funny `for` loop, personally I'd prefer:

```
current = head;
while(current)  // or current != nullptr to be more explicit
```

Note also that you (unnecessarily, of course) assign `head` to `current` twice - immediately before the `for` loop, and in the initialisation of it.

A simple scheme (but not at all efficient!) might be to just swap 'out of order' elements as you iterate through the list, until no swaps were necessary:

```
bool changeMade;
do{
    changeMade = false;
    current = head;
    while( current ){
        temp = current;
        current = current->next;

        if( current && current->data < temp->data ){
            changeMade = true;
            swap( temp->data, current->data );
        }
    }
} while( changeMade );
```

This assumes a `data` field is the only other in the node - since it doesn't actually swap the nodes, just the data. (Doing the former is not really any more difficult - but without seeing your node type declaration I'd be making up names and risk confusing the issue.)

Comment: std::sort requires random access iterators, and list classes normally don't support random access iterators. std::list:sort would work, but the list nodes are internal to std::list, and the original post is implementing it's own list class nodes and functions.

Comment: Slightly confused with the line swap( temp->data, current->data );

Comment: What is this and what is the swap bit?

Comment: @Ryan Just a function to swap the values in those locations. I pulled it out just for brevity really, and also because I don't know the type of `data`, or if there are multiple data fields.

Comment: I added my header file to the question so it avoids confusion

Comment: @Ryan Yes, but not at the time I wrote it. All you need to do is swap the integer values, my `data` is your `number` - I thought the function name would make this sufficiently clear..

Comment: I know, was just saying

Comment: Unfortunately though after trying what you said, my numbers in the list just disappear from the console window

Comment: @Ryan - not sure what the issue would be. If you're just swapping numbers (the data), the list pointers should be unaffected. Can you update the original post to show you latest code attempt?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any declarations for current, head, and temp, but I assume they are pointers to node. Have you decided on a sort algorithm? Does the sort algorithm need to be efficient or is something with the performance of a bubble sort ok? With logic similar to a bubble sort, you can repeatedly move the node with the largest value to the end of the list. Or to save a bit of time, you could remove the node with the largest value from the original list and insert it into the front of a new list that would end up in sorted order. More efficient algorithms use logic based on merge sort.

To remove or swap nodes, using a pointer to pointer can avoid special handling for the first node of a list (the one pointed to by pList in this example):

```
NODE * SortList(NODE * pList)
{
NODE * pNew = NULL;                     /* sorted list */
NODE **ppNode;                          /* ptr to ptr to node */
NODE **ppLargest;                       /* ptr to ptr to largest node */
NODE * pLargest;                        /* ptr to largest node */
    while(pList != NULL){               /* while list not empty */
        ppLargest = &pList;             /*  find largest node */
        ppNode = &((*ppLargest)->next);
        while(NULL != *ppNode){
            if((*ppNode)->data > (*ppLargest)->data)
                ppLargest = ppNode;
            ppNode = &((*ppNode)->next);
        }
        pLargest = *ppLargest;          /* move node to new */
        *ppLargest = pLargest->next;
        pLargest->next = pNew;
        pNew = pLargest;
    }    
    return(pNew);
}
```

Comment: @Jasen - I accidentally posted my answer before it was complete. There is an answer now.

Comment: @Ryan - is that what you want to do, or would you consider removing the node and inserting it into a new list a better option? If this is homework, I'm not sure how much code we are supposed to do for you. Can you try to write the code that finds the largest node in the original list?

Comment: Yeah it's what I want to do but I have no idea where to start with it. I want to keep it as one list only

Comment: @Ryan - to move the largest node to the end, you'd scan the list and swap the current node with the next node if the current node's value is greater than the next node's value. The problem here is knowing when you're done. Using a flag that is cleared at the start of a scan and set if there are any swaps done during a scan, and then checking the flag to see if it's zero after a scan is one way to know when the sort is done.

Comment: @Ryan - note that removing nodes and adding them to a new list only requires one more pointer to node for the new list. Using a pointer to pointer to node to scan the list makes it easy to remove a node from a list.